# Who broke it. 3 person logic

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

D walks into a room and sees his computer is broken. He asks "Who broke my computer?".

> A says B did it
>
> B says A is lying
>
> C says he did not

Of the three, it is known that only one is trustworthy and the other two always lie.

**Can this be solved?**

Comment: "C says **he** did not." Who does that **he** referring to? is it himself (C)?

Comment: C is saying he most certainly did not break it

Comment: Do we know how many (if any) of the statements are true?  Do we know if any of the three (A, B, and C) usually tell the truth (or usually lie)?

Comment: It cannot be solved. The Question is unclear. you have to tell us how many liars there.

Comment: My bad. Of the three, it is known that only one is trustworthy and the other two always lie.

Comment: Can you edit that ^ into the question?

Comment: Did that as you commented. :)

Comment: An alternative puzzle could have been "D knows which people always lie and which people always tell the truth. He knows for certain who did it." Only liars or only honest people is impossible. One liar is ambiguous (but surprisingly, it clears the actual perpetrator of all blame), so it must be two liars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick logical analysis of the 3 statements reveals that

> C did it, and B is the one telling the truth.

If A were telling the truth,

> B must have done it, B is lying (ok), and C has to be lying, meaning he also did it (not ok).

If C were telling the truth,

> A is lying and B did not do it, and B is lying so A told the truth (contradiction).

Therefore,

> B is the only one who can be telling the truth, A is lying because B did not do it, and C is lying because he did it.

Comment: Instead of relying on the logical contradiction, you could say that if C told the truth, then A is lying, confirming B's statement (that A is lying), resulting in 2 truth tellers where we know there's only 1.

Comment: @Lawrence: admittedly, the accepted answer is not the most elegant way of proving the result, but hey! Green tick!

Comment: Haha - congratulations. :)

Answer (score 4):

A slightly shorter solution, assuming only 1 person did it:

> B says A is lying. If that's false, A is telling the truth, otherwise, B is telling the truth. Eitherway, C is lying, and must have done it.

Answer (score -1):

I will add another solution

> C is telling the truth

That implied

> B is lying, his sentence become "A is telling the truth"
>  The important point is that it is not an absolute truth but just B *thinking* A is telling the truth, it just implies a thought

And

> A is lying, so B did no break it

Therefore,

> A broke it.

Comment: Maybe downvoters could comment and point out the mistake. Read the second spoiler tag, that's the important point of my reasoning.